power supply with max current in pcb
I'm new to electronics and I have a question. I have a component on my board that requires 4 volts and 2 amps, and I need 5 volts for other devices. Should I use an adapter, or should I use something on my board to convert the voltage?

what about using 12v adaptor 2 A

That would give you 12 V, which would quickly destroy something that expects 4 V.

What is it that requires 4V? - that is very unusual.

If you want to be efficient then use an adapter for the largest current. So you would use a 4V 3A adapter (you need some extra current for the 5V line, which we also need to know the current for). In this case you would use a step up converter. It may also be difficult to find a 4V adapter, the more common voltage is 5V. Something like this might be a good starting point: https://www.digikey.com/en/products/detail/pololu-corporation/4941/19235993
The other way would be to use a 5V converter and step down to 4V. The output would need to be adjustable to get the 4V.
https://www.digikey.com/en/products/detail/pololu-corporation/2868/10451189
You could use two step down converters with a higher voltage, which would be less efficient, and more costly because you would need a step down converter for both
